# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(Object) from the type Set<String>

Tags: apex, map

I am trying to populate this Set (buildingIds) with string values, but I am getting the error: **Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(Object) from the type Set**.

I am returning some json and iterating through it trying to exact the "building ids" into a Apex Set to ensure uniqueness.

If I dump out the values using: listingAttribute.get(attributeName) within my for loop I see the value for the building id at each iteration of the loop, but it errors when I try to add it to my set.

My code is below:

```
 Map<String, Object> jsonResults = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSONResponse);
 Set<String> buildingIds = new Set<String>();

 List<Object> listBuildings = (List<Object>)jsonResults.get('buildings');

 for (Object buildingRecord: listBuildings ) {
    Map<String, Object> buildingAttributes = (Map<String, Object>)buildingRecord;

   for (String attributeName : buildingAttributes .keySet()) {

     if( attributeName == 'building_id') {
       buildingIds.add(buildingAttributes.get(attributeName)); // **errors here**
     }

   }
} // close outer for loop
```

How can I add the building Id to the set?

Answer (score 2):

Each of these two approaches below should work:

`buildingIds.add((String)buildingAttributes.get(attributeName));`

**Or**

`buildingIds.add(buildingAttributes.get(attributeName).toString());`

The problem is you try to add an Object into a Set of string.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to buildingIds.add((buildingAttributes.get(attributeName)).Id);

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your map:

```
Map<String, Object> buildingAttributes ...
```

has a signature where the `get` method returns `Object` (as there are various types involved) but your set requires `String`. This is a case where a cast is used: you know that the value is in fact a `String` when the name is 'building_id' so you can (and must) downcast:

```
buildingIds.add((String) buildingAttributes.get(attributeName));
```

(If the values are `Id` values, better to use `Set<String> buildingIds = new Set<Id>();` and downcast to `(Id)`.)